# How does flicker relate to a card like Ulamog's dispoiler

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was wondering how a card like [Flicker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flicker) and a card like [Ulamog's Despoiler](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ulamog%27s%20Despoiler) would work together. Since Ulamog's Despoiler returns a card from exile and flicker exiles a card snd then returns it would flicker return the card that was put into a graveyard to the battlefield or would it just stay in the graveyard? I tried to look at rule 400.7 but I got confused on if it would work. If anyone could help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: What are you trying to flicker here?  Something other than the Despoiler?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to flicker a permanent a opponent controls

Comment: They won't interact in any way.  You have to completely finish resolving Flicker then the Despoiler's trigger can resolve (or in the opposite order).  Basically you can't pick the two cards to move from exile to the graveyard while Flicker is resolving.  For Flicker, you move the card to exile then back to the battlefield before anything else can do anything.

Comment: Ok, thank you, do you know how it would work with a card like Admonition Angel?

Comment: @Bootskat If you want to know about cards which have significantly different effects from Flicker, please ask that in an entirely new question not as comments to this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast or resolve *anything* whilst the target of [Flicker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flicker) is in exile, as it is returned to the battlefield as part of the spell.

You could do it to the target of [Otherworldly Journey](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Otherworldly%20Journey), as that returns the card at the next end step. If you did, it would stay in the graveyard, the object in the exile zone that Journey is looking for is no more.

Answer (score 1):

Flicker and the Despoiler won't interact in the way you want them to.  You can't Flicker something to exile and then move it with the Despoiler while it is there.  The stack won't let you do that.

The stack defines the order things are done in.  You have to completely finish resolving one spell / ability before you can start resolving another or put something else on the stack.

So if you cast Flicker targetting an opponent's Hill Giant, the stack looks like this:

- (top of stack)
- Flicker
- (bottom of stack)

If you start resolving Flicker without anyone responding, it will move the Hill Giant to exile then immediately back to the battlefield before you can do anything else.

If you were to cast Despoiler and respond with Flicker you still end up in the same situation.  The stack would look like this:

- (top of stack)
- Flicker
- Despoiler
- (bottom of stack)

You'd resolve Flicker (moving the Hill Giant to exile and immediately back to the battlefield).  Then you'd go to resolve the Despoiler.  At that point the Hill Giant wouldn't be in exile so you couldn't touch it with the Despoiler.

And just to be clear, you couldn't put them in the other order on the stack under normal circumstances (you can't cast a creature while the stack isn't empty).  Even if you could with some shenanigans, the Despoiler would resolve before Flicker while the Hill Giant is still on the battlefield.